# Wordpress database update post meta

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress

I have an Excel file containing the names of my pages and posts.

I inquired with ChatGPT about the SQL queries for:

**-Updating the ALT of the images**

```
     UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET 
    meta_value = CASE
                    WHEN post_id = 'ID1' AND meta_key = '_wp_attachment_image_alt' THEN 'new_alt_text1'
                    WHEN post_id = 'ID2' AND meta_key = '_wp_attachment_image_alt' THEN 'new_alt_text2'
                    -- Add other conditions for each ID and alt text
                END
WHERE post_id IN ('ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', ...) AND meta_key = '_wp_attachment_image_alt';
```

**-Updating posts informations:**

```
  UPDATE wp_posts
SET 
    post_date = CASE
                    WHEN ID = 'ID1' THEN 'new_date1'
                    WHEN ID = 'ID2' THEN 'new_date2'
                    -- Add other conditions for each ID and new date
                END,
    post_modified = CASE
                        WHEN ID = 'ID1' THEN 'new_date_modified1'
                        WHEN ID = 'ID2' THEN 'new_date_modified2'
                        -- Add other conditions for each ID and new modified date
                    END,
    post_title = CASE
                    WHEN ID = 'ID1' THEN 'new_title1'
                    WHEN ID = 'ID2' THEN 'new_title2'
                    -- Add other conditions for each ID and new title
                END
WHERE ID IN ('ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', ...);
```

**-Updating the Yoast SEO meta**

```
  UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET 
    meta_value = CASE
                    WHEN post_id = 'ID1' AND meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_canonical' THEN 'new_canonical_url1'
                    WHEN post_id = 'ID2' AND meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_canonical' THEN 'new_canonical_url2'
                    -- Add other conditions for each ID of canonical URL
                    WHEN post_id = 'ID3' AND meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' THEN 'new_meta_description3'
                    WHEN post_id = 'ID4' AND meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' THEN 'new_meta_description4'
                    -- Add other conditions for each ID of meta-description
                END
WHERE 
    (post_id = 'ID1' AND meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_canonical')
    OR (post_id = 'ID2' AND meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_canonical')
    OR (post_id = 'ID3' AND meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc')
    OR (post_id = 'ID4' AND meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc');
```

Can you confirm that these query will work to update the informations I asked on Pages and Posts ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to run the queries? You could back up your WordPress database before running, run the query, and see the result. If the result was not to your liking or did not work, then you could restore using the backup. Even better, copy your database and install it in a development server, run the queries, to verify that it will work properly.